# Java Fuzzy Search for an entity name with typos as well as abbrevations

Tags: java, fuzzy-search

I need to implement in Java a Fuzzy Search for an entity name say manufacturer name that will take care of the

```
(a) typos, as well as 
(b) shortened forms like limited, Ltd, etc
```

Say I need to identify that all the following 1 thru 7 refer to the same entity while 8 thru 9 is another entity :

```
1) Information System Technlogies
2) Info System Technlogies
3) Info System Techlology Limited
4) Info System Techlology Ltd
5) Information System Technlogies Limited
6) Info System Ltd
7) IS Limited
8) Delivery System Technologies Limited
9) DS Limited
```

Using `Lavenshtein Distance`, won't 5 and 8 look more similar and 7 and 9 will appear to be more similar when actually its other way round in both the cases.

I do not want to have to maintain a pre-defined dictionary for abbreviations as we have big data situation where pre-empting all the possibilities may not be feasible.

Any pointers if any single fuzzy method can help here for typos as well as abbreviations or I need to go hybrid and what would be best to use in that case please?

Comment: That might be hard to do, since how do you _know_ that `DS` isn't a typo and that `IS` stands for `Information Systems` and not `Industrial Solutions` etc.?

Comment: ok. Point understood. So, with a dictionary for Abbrevations, how can I go about this please? 6 & 7 will still look more dis-similar while 7 & 9 will look more similar when they are not. Thanks in advance!